# How to perform search operation on same controller in spring

Tags: spring-mvc

i m new to spring framework. I want to perform search operation on user details. on page load i was able to display list of users. now i want to perform some search operation on displayed user list. so on search button how can i perform search operation? on search button it calls controller which perform some search operation then it return list of users.

Comment: write a method in controller which should perform search operation. in model, you will use query with where clause. and access model values on view.

Comment: @MLS: On page load i m displaying list of users. Then i want to select specific user from list of users. for this i m using check box. so can i pass list of selected user from jsp to controller> so that i will perform some operation on this user

Comment: u can set id of user in hidden value and receive it in controller and fetch record of that user in model.

Comment: @MLS: i want to transfer list of users not a single user id.

Comment: compute ur search on jsp in scriplets, put list in session, and get it on controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can post checkedvalues array like name='mycheckbox[]' , and get them on controller, you already have list of users in controller , so find records from that list against received checked values. no need to pass list of users from jsp to controller.